# What is the difference between using Django form and manually setting date fields?

Tags: django

I am getting date/time info from ajax to Django. I am using 2 different views. `event_edit` is working fine, but `event_edit_new` does not work. It return an error `Enter a valid date/time.`

My question is what is making difference. They are getting exactly same information but one is ok while other one is not.

Javascript code making ajax request:

```
var ajax_test = function(event){

    $.ajax({
      url: '/scheduler/event/' + event.eventId + '/edit2/',
      method: 'POST', // 'POST' or 'PUT'
      data: {
        'Note': event.title,
        'OpNum': event.resourceId,
        'StartTime' : event.start.format(),
        'StopTime' : event.end.format(),
        'ScheduleNum': event.eventId,

      }
    }).done(function(res) {
      console.log("done", res)


    }).fail(function(error) {
      console.error("error", error)
      console.log(event.start.format());
    });
  }
```

2 views

```
def event_edit(request, pk):
    schedule = get_object_or_404(Schedule, pk=pk)

    schedule.OpNum = request.POST.get('OpNum')
    schedule.Note = request.POST.get('Note')
    schedule.StartTime = request.POST.get('StartTime')
    schedule.StopTime = request.POST.get('StopTime')
    schedule.ScheduleNum =request.POST.get('ScheduleNum')
    schedule.save()

    return HttpResponse('ok')


def event_edit_new(request, pk):

    schedule = get_object_or_404(Schedule, pk=pk)

    if request.method =='POST':
        form = ScheduleForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = schedule)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()          
            return HttpResponse('ok')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('error')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('done')
```

Comment: Show us the model of `Schedule`

Comment: please share `ScheduleForm`

Answer (score 1):

In your first view, there is no validation applied to user data input:

```
schedule.StartTime = request.POST.get('StartTime')
schedule.StopTime = request.POST.get('StopTime')
```

[`request.POST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) does not validate any data so that will grab user data exactly as submitted and set it on a model. Note that it might work but it is not guaranteed to work if user will ever send datetime format the application does not understand. For example try submitting something like `"invalid date"` and you should get 500 error.

Your second view on the other hand uses a [Django Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/) to validate user input. By using a form you are validating user input before processing it in any way. You did not paste how your form is structured however if you are getting `Enter a valid date/time.` this means Django form did not validate one of the datetime fields. There are couple of reasons why that might be:

- submitted datetime does is not one of [`input_formats`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateTimeField) for a `DateTimeField`. You can customize the formats with:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    datetime_field = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', ...])
```

- submitted datetime is not one of Django's default supported datetime formats. 
  You can customize them with [`DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS) setting.